# Google Calendar parallax effect

Tags: html, parallax

I am trying to build an HTML5 app that will show dates and events and would like to use something like the Google Calendar app's parallax effect where the date scrolls up to the top of the screen with the events and then stays there while the events continue to scroll, until replaced by another date.

Would appreciate any direction / help with the HTML and how to use the libraries involved.

Comment: What have you already tried? any sample code?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it - you can easily do it with the jquery pin plugin https://github.com/webpop/jquery.pin